# Proof that if $K$ compact then $ \text{diam} (K) < \infty $

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, metric-spaces, compactness

I have the following question but without any correction so I will really appreciate a feedback on my answers.

**Question:**
Let be $K$ a non-empty compact metric space. We define $ \text{diam} (K) = \sup \left \{ d(a, b): a,b \in K  \right \}$. Show that $\text{diam} (K) < \infty$ and $\exists a,b \in K$ such that $\text{diam} (K)= d(a, b)$.

**My Answer:**
*Prove that  $\text{diam} (K) < \infty$*

By absurd we suppose that $\text{diam} (K) = \infty$. It means that there exists at least one strictly increasing sequence defined WLOG, as follow: $(u_n=d(a,b_n))_n$ verifying $u_n \underset{n \to \infty}{\rightarrow} \infty$ and this for any given fixe $a \in K$.
Hence we can not extract a convergent (in $K$) subsequence from $u_n$. And this contradict the definition of $K$ being a compact set.

*Prove that  $\exists a,b \in K$ such that $\text{diam}(K)= d(a,b)$*

We writte $\text{diam}(K)=C$.
Now we define by reccurence the following sequence:

- We take $a_0,b_0$ as we want in $K$ and $u_0=d(a_0,b_0) \leq C$
- We choose $a_1, b_1 \in K$ s.t. $0 \leq C- d(a_0,b_0) < u_1=d(a_1,b_1) \leq C$. Such $a_1, b_1$ has to exists by the definition of $C$. Indeed it is not the case we get $d(a_0;b_0)=C$ (and this completes the proof).
- ... same for all $u_n$...

So we have $u_n \underset{n \to \infty}{\rightarrow} C $ and the subsequence $(a_{nk} ; b_{nk})$ that must cvge to $(a;b)$ by the compactness of $K$ verifies too $u_{nk} \underset{k \to \infty}{\rightarrow} K $ by the uniqueness of the limit. $ \Rightarrow d(a_{nk},b_{nk}) \underset{n \to \infty}{\rightarrow} d(a,b)=C$

Is this correct? thank you.

Comment: @Infinity_hunter thank for your answer correct

Comment: More generally you can prove that continuous real valued function on compact set attains supremum. In your question you can take $K×K$ be that compact set and also you can show $d$ to be continuous.

Comment: @Infinity_hunter thk for your time can you writte what you ve said me in a more details answer please. Moreover  does the first part correct? (and what about the second part if you have time?) thk

Comment: For the first part of the proof, you can let $a \in K$ be fixed, but it requires a little bit of justification. For the second part of the proof, it is not necessarily the case that $(d(a_n,b_n))_n < C$ increasing implies $d(a_n,b_n) \to C$; you need to appeal to the definition of the supremum. However, both of these are easy fixes, and the essence of the reasoning is very good for both parts. For the very last part, it may be worth remarking that $d(a_{n_k}, b_{n_k}) \to d(a,b)$ because $d$ is continuous (or perhaps this is obvious and it's not necessary to state it).

Comment: @legionwhale thank a lot for your answer. Concerning the part on the definition of the supremum it includes when I writte "by the definition of $C$" but I am agree that it is not clear enough.

Comment: thk a lot. if you can re writte my proof in the answer to make it clearer and like this I will mark this topic as solved (i will be happy to read it). Again thk for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first prove that $\text{diam}(K) < \infty$.

*Proof 1*

Suppose not. Then, $\exists (a_n), (b_n) \in K$ such that $d(a_n,b_n) \uparrow  \infty$.

Now observe that, for any $x \in K$, we have: $$d(a_n, b_n) \le d(a_n, x) + d(b_n,x)$$

In particular, LHS $\uparrow \infty \implies \sup \{d(a_n,x), d(b_n, x)\} = \infty$. Therefore, $K$ is not bounded. But every compact metric space is totally bounded, so this is a contradiction. $\square$

*Proof 2*

We continue from work done in the first proof.

As we showed, $\sup \{d(a_n,x), d(b_n, x)\} = \infty$ for any $x \in K$.

Therefore, if we fix an arbitrary $x \in K$, we may pick $u_k \in \{a_n\} \cup \{b_n\}$ such that $d(x, u_k) \to \infty$.

Suppose that $(u_k)$ has a convergent subsequence $u_{k_l} \to u \in K$. Then, by the continuity of the metric $d$,

$$d(x, u_{k_l}) \to d(x,u)$$

But $\lim_{l} d(x, u_{k_l}) = \infty$, so this is a contradiction. $\square$

*Remark*: I think a little more justification than you gave was also needed for the last part of this proof.

---

We now prove that the supremum $s := \text{diam}(K)$ may be attained.

By definition of the supremum, $\exists (a_n), (b_n) \in K$ such that $d(a_n,b_n) \uparrow s$.

Further, as $K$ is sequentially compact, we may find a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ which converges (say, to $a$). Now consider the sequence $(b_{n_k})$. By appeal to sequential compactness again, this further has a convergent subsequence(!) $b_{{n_{k_l}}} \to b$.

The good news is that we still have $a_{{n_{k_l}}} \to a$. Therefore, by the continuity of $d$, we may deduce that:

$$d(a, b) = \lim_l d(a_{{n_{k_l}}}, b_{{n_{k_l}}}) = s$$

so the supremum is attained.

*Remarks*: I changed my mind again; continuity of the metric is required to prove this! Also, note that it is necessary to apply sequential compactness twice here. It is not entirely obvious that there exists $(n_k)$ such that both $(a_{n_k}), (b_{n_k})$ simultaneously converge, as you asserted in your proof.

---

*Proof suggested by Infinity Hunter*

Let $K$ be compact. Then, by Tychonoff, $K \times K$ is also compact. Hence, the image of the continuous function $d : K \times K \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and attains its bounds. This implies exactly that $\text{diam}$ has a finite value which is achieved by some pair of points.

(If you are not familiar with any of the results I quoted, you should be able to find proofs for all of them in any textbook, or even on this site.)